# "Order something to be done" or "order something done"?

Tags: grammar

Shouldn't have "to be" been used in the following sentence, if not, then why?

> Instead, President Johnson ordered all land (**to be**) returned to it is former owners.

It is from [Crash Course US history](https://youtu.be/nowsS7pMApI). It is at 2 minute and 5 second.

Comment: This is a fairly common idiom. It is difficult to say whether it is strictly 'correct'. However it is easily understood by native speakers.

Comment: The phrase "… *returned to it is former owners* ." is broken English. It is very ungrammatical. The presenter actually says: ***its*** **former owners**

Answer (score 1):

That Crash Course you always ask about is usually not very good.

"To order something be done or to be done" is **not great**. Normal usage triggers: order someone to do something.

"I **order you** to do this immediately." That's the right way to use it.

**"He ordered his men** to return all land immediately".

And **you can't really order land (give orders to land)**, you order a person to do something. You can, though, **order food in a restaurant**.

So, it really should be:

He ordered administration officials to return the land to former owners immediately.

He ordered his lieutenant (to) do that immediately.