# Use "order sth. done" or "order sth. to be done"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I've seen the problem mentioned in ["Order something to be done" or "order something done"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/184704/154414) , but this can't help me with my doubt. Plus, this two phrases is really confusing for Chinese English learners like me.

Can anyone tell me briefly the difference between them?
Or at least, which one should I use in the following sentence?

> He ordered an animal ____(made/to be made) in the likeness of his description and used in festivals from then on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "full" form is *He ordered an animal **to be made...***, but ***to be*** can be omitted as a stylistic choice. Less commonly, perhaps, you can omit just the infinitive marker ***to*** - *He ordered [that] an animal **be made...*** Note that the "subordinator" ***that*** should only be included if you *don't* include ***to***. I don't think the particular stylistic choice of phrasing here makes any difference to the meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My English teacher told me that due to the phrase "from then on", only "to be made" can be used here. Is he right?

Comment: I can't imagine why your English teacher would say that, but it's certainly not true. Whether or not you append the adverbial element ***from then on*** (or alternatives such as ***thenceforth***, or ***immediately***, for example) makes absolutely no difference to the syntax of the preceding assertion. In your context, *He ordered it **to be made...*** would be the most common form, but *He ordered [that] it **be made...*** and *He ordered it **made...*** are perfectly "valid" (though somewhat "stylised") alternatives.

Comment: Note that if we substitute the near-equivalent verb ***command*** for ***order***, almost all native speakers would choose the ***that-** clause* subordinator: *He **commanded that it be made...*** (or perhaps the more explicitly subjunctive *He commanded that it **should** be made...*). So my advice to you is to allow for the possibility of (competent) Anglophones using any of the forms I've given above (i.e. - accept them as "valid" if you encounter them). But for your *own* output, I suggest you stick with ***that-*** clauses: *He ordered / commanded / insisted **that it be done***.

Comment: I've got it. Thanks very much!